# how to get http status code in a web client written in c

Tags: c

I am currently building an http web client using sockets which gets a url as input and should perform the following task: Connect to the web server and save the response of the server in a file, and print the status code included in the http response.

I have completed the first part of writing in a file and I am having a problem with retrieving the status code. Is there a library or a function that could help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) to perform the HTTP request.

And the function [curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) to get the HTTP code.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the response is the status line, and is very easy to parse. It consists of the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its associated textual phrase ("OK", "Not Found" etc).

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The exact syntax and the list of valid codes is documented in [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (section 6.1).